# Twitter's new approach of third party application? How would you see this move as developer.... especially you plan to build a twitter client

Tags: social-networks, planning, twitter, third-party-libraries

Just today morning I have read news that twitter has issued a warning to developers not to make any new third party client, the official announcement can be read [here](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/c82cd59c7a87216a?pli=1).

As a programmer, how do you see this move of twitter? Does it seems that they want to standardize the behavior of third party client or they don't want any new client in favor of the default clients they have made?

What if anybody wants to create a new client? Is there any guidelines that-if followed- ensure that we can create a new mobile client? Or we should stop thinking about it? What are the option for the developers who want to build some clients for twitter?

I can realize that I have asked too many questions, but I still think that there can be one common answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The announcement basically says "You must not duplicate the official twitter app" and "you must write your client that it looks like the official client" - those two just don't match.

Time to optimize clients for status.net/identi.ca and switch over .....

Comment: Are you sure more users will flock to status.net and identi.ca? sounds funny but I had not used those networks yet, Twitter is more popular than these sites. Don't you think developers have to start from the scratch??

Comment: There will be a group of users that will move over. For sure not the mainstream. The api of status.net is similar enough to twitter to implement the most basic things by just having a different api endpoint. Status.net has the advantage that you can have private (=organization internal) instances. But then Justin Bieber will probably never be on status.net.

Comment: That's where the money is... it's difficult to attract users to use a social network client if it doesn't have twitter and/or facebook. Its worrying when you plan something big and serious on those platforms and suddenly they are pulling the strings...

Answer (score 4):

Another company gets big, turns evil. That is all.